# loop to generate means for each factor

Tags: r

A "toy" version of the dataset looks something like this. There are three groups of patients at three time points represented by group_time variable. In the actual dataset there more patients and more variables.

```
patientid <- c(100,100,100,101,101,101,102,102,102,103,103,103,104,104,104)
group_time <- c(group1_1, group1_2, group1_3, group2_1, group2_2, group2_3, group1_1, group1_2, group1_3, group3_1, group3_2, group3_3)
variable1 <- c(4,7,2,4,9,12,15,12,17,5,2,23)
variable2 <- c(5,6,12,34,92,24,55,92,17,53,21,28)
variable3 <- c(0,23,18,44,52,94,15,93,47,57,28,18)
variable4 <- c(1,43,58,44,12,44,55,63,44,32,29,19)
variable5 <- c(3,46,68,55,33,45,12,19,43,37,22,21)

Data<- data.frame(patientid=patientid,group=group)
```

How would I create a loop to get the mean for each group_time factor for each variable. I believe the code for getting the mean is following:

```
tapply(clean_data$variable), clean_data$group_time, mean)
```

But I want to create a loop that can specify multiple variable columns to generate the means and then output as a df with the means organized with group_time as the rows and the variables as the columns. Like so but for all 5 variables:

```
group_time <- c(group1_1, group1_2, group1_3, group2_1, group2_2, group2_3, group3_1, group3_2, group3_3)
variable 1 <- c(c(mean of group1_1 for variable 1, mean of group1_2 for variable 1, mean of group1_3 for variable 1, mean of group2_1 for variable 1, mean of group2_2 for variable 1, mean of group2_3 for variable 1, mean of group3_1 for variable 1, mean of group3_2 for variable 1, mean of group3_3 for variable 1)

Data<- data.frame(group_time=group_time,variable1=variable1)
```

Comment: Can you check the data that you have shared? It returns an error `Error: object 'group1_1' not found`

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your data and created my own solution for the means for each group_time.

Moreover, I made the data slightly more tidier to work with.

Also, I noticed that the patientid vector was not the same length of the other vectors, so I had removed patient 104 .

```
library(tidyverse)

patientid <- c(100,100,100,101,101,101,102,102,102,103,103,103)
group_time <- c("group1_1", "group1_2", "group1_3", "group2_1", "group2_2", "group2_3", "group1_1", "group1_2", "group1_3", "group3_1", "group3_2", "group3_3")
variable1 <- c(4,7,2,4,9,12,15,12,17,5,2,23)
variable2 <- c(5,6,12,34,92,24,55,92,17,53,21,28)
variable3 <- c(0,23,18,44,52,94,15,93,47,57,28,18)
variable4 <- c(1,43,58,44,12,44,55,63,44,32,29,19)
variable5 <- c(3,46,68,55,33,45,12,19,43,37,22,21)


df <- data.frame(patient_id=patientid, 
                 group_time = group_time,
                 variable1 = variable1,
                 variable2 = variable2,
                 variable3 = variable3,
                 variable4 = variable4,
                 variable5 = variable5
                 )
#tidying the data by separating the groups and times 
df <- as_tibble(df) %>% separate(group_time,c("group","time"),"_")

#gathering all variables under variable and assigning it a value 
df <-   pivot_longer(
    data=df,
    cols= variable1:variable5 , 
    names_to = "variable", 
    values_to = "value"
    )

  means <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(group,time,variable) %>% 
  summarise(
    mean = mean(value)
  )

means
```

Hope this helped

Comment: this is very helpful. thank you. In my actual dataset I have 50 variables of interest that I want this code repeated for (ie. 50 means grouped by group and time). Is there a way to specify the code to get the means for these 50 columns rather than have to type out variable 1, variable 2.... 50 times.

Comment: @BenjaminKrick I updated the answer , just change the cols argument in the pivot_longer function to variable1:variable50 . I use pivot longer because one variable (the value) is spread across one observation. essentially it makes the df longer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that produced the answer I needed, assuming that the variables of interest are the first 5 in the data frame:

`group_time_means <- sapply(data[1:5], tapply, INDEX=data$group_time, mean, na.rm=T)`